# VueJS/Vuex Initial state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I need to load some data from backend **before** my app starts. Ideally I'd put some kind of loader.

I use vuex and I keep all necessary data in store. There might be few actions I need to call and they must be finished before app starts.

So I can't figure out how to do this. I use vue webpack template, and the only solution I came across is something like wait after all actions finish and only then initialize app with `new Vue`. But this looks very ugly.

Comment: You could trigger actions in `beforeCreate()` hook https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: Yes, but how to stop lifecycle until those actions finished? I don't want other components to be created before I get data

Comment: Cite from [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeCreate): Called synchronously after the instance has just been initialized, before data observation and event/watcher setup. So, try it.

Comment: Well, I tried it. But as I expected, vuex action is async, so I didn't get necessary data in child components. Root lifecycle has finished before vuex action was completed. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Looks like you're right, and beforeCreate doesn't stop the entire app from executing. I personally preload data in created() hooks, and set 'loading' animation until it's done in my apps.

Comment: Yep, but my components are throwing errors because they can't find necessary data =\

Comment: `v-if` everything that relies on the data that isn't loaded.

Comment: Hi, what if this state is being used in vue-router for navigation guards? Like initialize logged in user and then redirect to the path accordingly.